# Not getting desired output in this simple program?

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char a[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%c",&a[i]);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%c",a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

//string is not duplicating exactly
//scanf takes enter as a string but why?

Comment: Because your professor wanted it to.

Comment: _What_ output are you expecting?

Comment: @user3121023 you are right but please can you explain?

Answer (score 3):

Your code actually behaves the way it should. Upon entering `3abc` the program will print out `abc`.
I guess what you aimed for instead was entering `3` then pressing enter and entering `abc` and upon pressing enter again `abc` should be printed out. In order to do so, you have to adjust the first scanf call.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;int n;
    scanf("%d\n",&n); //add \n in order to read the "pressing enter"
        char a[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%c",&a[i]);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%c",a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```